# plt.figure(figsize=(10,20)) is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using  **matplotlib.pyplot** to plot a histogram and i want to increase the size of the plot. The code to plot is:

```
plt.hist(x)
plt.xlabel("Months")
plt.ylabel("Donated")
plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
plt.show()
```

But plt.figure(..) is not having any affect on the size of the the graph. I am using Spyder IDE.

Comment: put plt.figure() first then plt.hist(x)

Comment: @BryceWayne It worked, thanks

Comment: of course. Remember to define your space prior to plotting.

Comment: Please mark the answer correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to define your figure space prior to creating the plot information.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
plt.hist(x)
plt.xlabel("Months")
plt.ylabel("Donated")
plt.show()
```

This will define your figure then plot information in that space, otherwise Matplotlib will use defaults.

Answer (score 3):

Just put it at the top:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,20))
plt.hist(x)
plt.xlabel("Months")
plt.ylabel("Donated")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In matplotlib, we've to create the figure first if we plan to have any pyplot function on non-default figure dimentions.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,4)) ## New figure
plt.hist(x)
plt.xlabel("Months")
plt.ylabel("Donated")
plt.show()
```

From [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html), "Each pyplot function makes some change to a figure", and by default a figure is created to put all pyplot changes.

Make use of the function gca() to return current axes (a matplotlib.axes.Axes instance), and gcf() to return current figure (matplotlib.figure.Figure instance)

### Debug:

```
print(plt.gcf()) # Figure(432x288) default
plt.figure(figsize=(10,20)) # --> (1)
plt.hist(x)
plt.xlabel("Months")
plt.ylabel("Donated")
print(plt.gcf()) # Figure(720x1440) from (1)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20)) # --> (2)
print(plt.gcf()) # Figure(1440x1440) from (2)
```